# How to make 2 condition in button clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello is that possible to make two condition from 1 button clicked?

```
if(unable == 4) {
    $("#formitem").submit(function () {
        $("#order_4").appendTo("body");
        var message = "<?=$message_change_location?>";
        var resotid = <?=$restaurant_info["restaurant_id"]?>;
        var restoname = "<?=$restaurant_info["restaurant_name"]?>";
        var restomenu = "<?=$restaurant_menu?>";
        var postal = "<?=$postal?>";
        var delivery_no = "<?=$delivery_no?>"
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/order_unable",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                message_change_location: message,
                restid: resotid,
                restname: restoname,
                restmenu: restomenu,
                postal: postal,
                delivery_no: delivery_no,
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $("#order_4_show").html(res);
                $("#order_4").modal("show");
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
 }else if($("#second_notif") == "show"){
            $("#formitem").submit(function () {
                alert("asdf");
        });
```

I want to make a condition if `second_notif` is showed, than if i click `$("#formitem")` for the second times will show the alert. The first click will show  pop up windows, and there is not any problem here.

in the pop up windows there is a script to show the `second_notif`, with this following code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change_location_2").click(function () {
        $(".vendor-heading").hide();
        $(".location-header").hide();
        $("#order_4").modal("hide");
        $("#second_notif").show();
        return true;
    });
});

</script>
```

and there in same page on where to show the pop up windows there is a code to show the `second_notif` too :

```
$("#change_location").click(function(){
    $(".vendor-heading").hide();
    $(".location-header").hide();
    $("#second_notif").show();
    return true;
});
```

here is the view for the `second_notif` :

```
<div id="second_notif" style="display:none;">
     <?php $this->load->view('MAIN/'.country_code.'/search');?>
</div>
```

I can show the pop up windows, and show the `second_notif` when i clicked `formitem` button, but when the `second_notif` has been showed and if i clicked the same button again, why i cant show the alert?
guys can you help me how to show the alert?

p.s alert is not my goal, i will change the alert to other view 
please help me guys, thank you (:

Comment: That's a lot of code.  I suggest only including the essential bits in your question.

Comment: @AnthonyAstige the first code is the main code, i just put the other code to explain my code to be clear

Comment: it is a bit long but I'll read it and see if I can be of assistance :)

Comment: Why Not use the condition inside the submit event. As of now the event first registered in your case  `if(unable == 4) {` will always be called. So, Just move the logic inside event block...

Comment: @Runcorn i have tried that but still cant get the alert, do  u know how to get the alert if `second_notif` has been showed?

Comment: Just use ... if("#second_notif").is(":visible") case...

Comment: @Runcorn nice try! but you are late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you only need one event handler for this method. You can then move your conditionals into the handler.

Secondly, your condition `$('#second-notif') == 'show'` will not work, as is will never evaluate to true. To test if an element is visible using jQuery, use the `.is(':visible')` method. Here's a quick example of what you're looking for:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uckz2o8p/)

Comment: thank you! its works! `.is(':visible')` there is a condtion where im trying to use, because im sure `$('#second-notif') == 'show'` is wrong code for the condition

Answer (score 0):

Bind the two element in single handler

```
$("#change_location_2, #change_location").click(function () {
        $(".vendor-heading").hide();
        $(".location-header").hide();
        $("#order_4").modal("hide");
        $("#second_notif").show();
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: i cant bind, that element, because its from 2 different view, anyway that is not any problem in this code, i just want to know how to get another condition if i clicked `formitem` for the second times

Answer (score 0):

how if you add condition to form submit like this ?

```
$("#formitem").submit(function () {
     if(unable == 4) {
        $("#order_4").appendTo("body");
        var message = "<?=$message_change_location?>";
        var resotid = <?=$restaurant_info["restaurant_id"]?>;
        var restoname = "<?=$restaurant_info["restaurant_name"]?>";
        var restomenu = "<?=$restaurant_menu?>";
        var postal = "<?=$postal?>";
        var delivery_no = "<?=$delivery_no?>"
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/order_unable",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                message_change_location: message,
                restid: resotid,
                restname: restoname,
                restmenu: restomenu,
                postal: postal,
                delivery_no: delivery_no,
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $("#order_4_show").html(res);
                $("#order_4").modal("show");
            }

        });
        return false;
     }else if($("#second_notif") == "show"){
        alert("asdf");
     }
});
```